# ¿Porque cuando reinicio el tomcat 8 mis usuarios creados se borran?

Tags: xml, tomcat

Mi problema con tomcat es que le cambio cosas en `tomcat-users` ya que por default no tiene ni rol ni un usuario, pues yo se lo pongo. Hasta ahí todo bien me funciona correctamente y no hay problema, pero cuando por alguna razón reinicio el servidor o prendo y apago y quiero volver a entrar al manager de tomcat, me pide la contraseña y el usuario, pero este ya no esta almacenado sino mas bien eliminado y no se si tomcat vuelva a crear esos archivos.

¿Como le hago para que ya no me borre esa parte del archivo?

Estas son  las lineas que agrego.

```
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="1234" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Actualmente estoy usando el tomcat 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era que en eclipse se actualizan los `paths` por default cada vez que se inicia el servidor, para resolver el problema hice lo siguiente:

darle doble clic en el servidor de tomcat 8, abrirá una ventana con varias opciones y donde se da clic en `publishing` y después en la sección de `select publishing actions` se desactiva la opción de `update context paths`